# Best Way to Handle a Rich Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have been doing some android basic projects for one of my client. Now I have to develop an application for him in android which will be a slideshow. I have done using this using viewFlipper and everything is perfect till now. Now my client wants to add animation in each slide, but these animations will be totally different for each slide (although they will be basic alpha, scale and rotate animations). So I am confused what's the best way to achieve this? One way is to create xml for each animation and apply on each imageview or create animation function for each imageview. But that seems more and more work for even a simple fadein for imageview bcoz imageview will be at different position on each slide.

I wish if there were a Tweener kind of thing (like in actionscript in flash) where I could define just properties for that imageview and create animation by just one line of code.

Or is there any easy way to achieve this. Will be really grateful if you can help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Window manager could be your probable solution.
its kind of isolated layer from the xml or layout on your Screen.
you can add child and their attributes with this manager.

WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

read more:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html